# [SPDY][HTTP2] Perform custom server push with netty

Tags: netty, spdy, http2

I don't know how I can perform under netty a custom server push using SPDY and/or HTTP2 protocol.

For example, I can do it:

- with a PushStrategy in jetty: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.2.v20140723/spdy-implementing-push.html
- with a ServerConnection in undertow: https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/ServerConnection.java#L230

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout this article. I think it should help with SPDY
https://github.com/eigengo/opensourcejournal/blob/master/2014.1/spdynetty/spdynetty.md